# structured arguments as variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic

I've a method needing two parameters: An alias (string) and an object (of any type).

Now I would like to have a (template) method taking n of those pairs; The syntax should look like this:

```
append (
  { "first", int { 3 } },
  { "second", double { 2. } },
  { "third", std::string { "test" } }
);
```

What I currently do is following:

```
void append() {}

template<typename Type>
void append(std::string str, Type obj)
{
  std::cout << "str: " << str << " type: " << obj << "\n";
}

template<typename Type, typename... Args>
void append(std::string str, Type t, Args... args)
{
  append(str, t);
  append(args...);
}

int main()
{
 append("first", 1, "second", 2., "third, "test");
}
```

Which makes it possible to write something like this

```
append (
  "first", int { 3 },
  "second", double { 2. },
  "third", std::string { "test" }
);
```

But in my opinion it would make the code more readable, if I could use the curly Braces like in my example above.

What I've tried to do is use a templated std::pair but all I get are compiler errors:

```
main.cpp:9:6: note: template<class Type> void 

append(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, Type> >)
 void append(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Type>> pair)
      ^
main.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:23:22: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Type’
  append({"first", 1});
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, braced initialization lists cannot be bound to non-typed template parameters, which is the fundamental problem here.

Comment: How about `append (
  std::make_pair("first", 3),
  std::make_pair("second", 2.),
  std::make_pair("third", std::string { "test" })
);` ?

Comment: You can probably use boost::assign or something similar `append(std::cout)("first", int{3})("second", double{ 2.0})("third", std::string{"test"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use boost::assign or something similar:

```
 class t_Append final
 {
     private: ::std::ostream & m_where;

     public: explicit
     t_Append
     (
         ::std::ostream & where
     ) noexcept
     :   m_where{where}
     {
         return;
     }

     public: explicit
     t_Append
     (
          t_Append && other
     ) noexcept
     :    m_where{other.m_where}
     {
          return;
     }

     public: template
     <
         typename x_Object
     > auto
     operator ()
     (
          char const * const psz_str
     ,    x_Object const & object
     ) &&
     {
          m_where << "str: " << psz_str << " type: " << object << "\n";
          return t_Append{::std::move(*this)};
     }
 };

 inline auto
 Append(::std::ostream & where)
 {
     return t_Append{where};
 }
```

usage:

```
 Append(::std::cout)
     ("first", int{3})
     ("second", double{2.0})
     ("third", ::std::string{"test"});
```

Comment: Why are you moving `*this` into a fresh `t_Append` to return? And I don't think you need to declare a move constructor

Comment: @Caleth The idea was to suppress `t_Append` class from being used as a functor and passed around. In original code it had `Append` as a friend and all the constructors were private so presence of user-defined move constructor prevents public copy / move constructors from being generated. Also note rvalue reference qualifier on `operator ()`.